# Invoke-RestMethod fails when calling Powershell from CMD.exe

Tags: rest, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have two Powershell Scripts that work perfectly fine together:

- The `Method` script, which accepts parameters to run `Invoke-RestMethod`.
- The `Caller` script, which sends parameters to `Method`.

In `Caller`, I define parameters and send them:

```
$file = "\\Share\Location\STUDENTS.txt"
$username = "d155a9dd-be60-9dcb-9009-02d634192545"
$type = "person"
$operation = "refresh"

& "\\Share\Location\Batch\method.ps1" $file $username $type $operation
```

In `Method`, I echo the variables and show the response back, for the following output:

```
FILE: \\Share\Location\STUDENTS.txt
USER: d155a9dd-be60-9dcb-9009-02d634192545
TYPE: person
OPER: refresh

Success: Feed File Uploaded.  Use the reference code 53a7c62c7f4a412889af3b15d712525b to track these records in the logs.
```

So far, so good. Now, I need to make `Caller` into a Windows batch file instead, so that I can bypass the execution policy when calling `Method`. I can't use the `-File` argument because Windows 10 doesn't support UNC paths in the command line so I use the `-Command` argument instead:

```bash
@ECHO OFF    
SET feedfile='\\Share\Location\STUDENTS.txt'
SET integration='d155a9dd-be60-9dcb-9009-02d634192545'
SET datatype='person'
SET action='refresh'

SET pscommand="& '\\Share\Location\Batch\method.ps1' %feedfile% %integration% %datatype% %action%"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %pscommand%
```

But the output I get from THAT script is:

```
FILE: \\Share\Location\STUDENTS.txt
USER: d155a9dd-be60-9dcb-9009-02d634192545
TYPE: person
OPER: refresh

Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

The same exact web request is sent in either case -- it fails with the batch file, but works flawlessly with Powershell script. What could the problem be?

Comment: I have the similar problem when file was running fine from PowerShell ISE but totally failing when running from cmd, In my case there were problems with variable scopes and visibility. In your case I think there also may be security restrictions when calling ps file from unc share.

Comment: Try omitting -NoProfile.  Does it work then?  If so, that should tell you that there's something in the profile that's causing your command to work.  Perhaps there's a https trust in your profile that's not available to Invoke-RestMethod when you add -NoProfile?

Comment: @DaveMarkle Nope, still nothing.

Comment: Besides the usual advice (don't use a batch file in the first place): Put the PowerShell commands in a script file (`.ps1`) and use the `-File` parameter to run the script. (Make sure that `-File` is the last parameter on PowerShell's command line.)